# Submersion to $ T^{2}$

Tags: complex-geometry, lattices

Let $ M$ be a $2n$-dimensional compact and connected manifold.
Suppose there is $\Omega\in\Omega^{1}(M,\mathbb{C}) $ a  closed complex form whose real and imaginary parts represent linearly independent rational cohomology classes and such that
$$ \omega^{n-1} \wedge \Omega \wedge \bar{\Omega}\neq 0$$ (Here $\omega$ is a symplectic form.)
Define $\Lambda=[\Omega]H_{1}(M,\mathbb{Z}) $. We define a map $\pi:M\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}/\Lambda $ by 
$$ \pi(p)=\int_{p_{0}}^{p}\Omega. $$

1) Why is$\Lambda$ a cocompact lattice?

2) Why is $\pi$ a surjective submersion?

Comment: It could be helpful if you explain what is meant by $[\Omega]H_{1}(M,\mathbb{Z})$

Comment: @DmitriPanov when I see the notation for the first time , I was confused. But I think  it is $< [\Omega], H_{1}(M,\ mathbb{Z})> as a natural pairing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Note first that $\Lambda\subset \mathbb C$ is a subgroup generated by a finite collection of numbers (periods) of the type $\alpha+i\beta$, where $\alpha,\, \beta\in \mathbb Q$. Such a subgroup is clearly discreet so it is either $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z^2$. The only possibility for such subgroup to be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ is when all such periods are proportional to each other (over $\mathbb Q$). However such periods can not be all proportional since otherwise the cohomology classes of $Re(\Omega)$ and $Im(\Omega)$ will be proportional. Hence the group of periods is $\mathbb Z^2$ and it is a lattice in $\mathbb C$.This proves the first assertion.
2. Assume by contradiction that the map $\pi$ is not surjective. In this case the pullback map $\pi^*: H^2(\mathbb C/\Lambda,\mathbb C)\to H^2(M, \mathbb C)$ is trivial. However by construction the class of $\Omega\wedge \overline \Omega$ belongs to the image of the latter map. This contradicts $\omega^{n-1}\wedge \Omega\wedge \overline \Omega\ne 0$.
3. Note that the $2n$-form $\omega^{n-1}\wedge\Omega\wedge \overline \Omega$ is vanishing at every point where the differential of $\pi$ has rank less than $2$. So in case  $\omega^{n-1}\wedge\Omega\wedge \overline \Omega$ is a non-vanishing volume form the map $\pi$ is submersive.

PS. Note that if case we only ask $\omega^{n-1}\wedge\Omega\wedge \overline \Omega$ to be non-zero in cohomology, $\pi$ need not be a submertion, it is easy construct such examples on $T^2$ - just take $\Omega$ that vanishes on a small open disk in $T^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Do you have advice that like $\pi$ make a surjective submersion?

Comment: Sorry, in fact I realised that it IS subversive if we ask that $\omega^{n-1}\wedge \Omega\wedge \overline \Omega$ is a never vanishing volume form. I  originally thought that you  only ask it to be non-zero as a cohomology class. Would you like me to adjust the answer?

Comment: I would be truely grateful if possible.

Comment: You are right I must be say it is Nowhere vanish volume form. Sorry

Comment: Dear Dimitri Panov I have question about prior mode of $\Omega$, and it’s not related to the this question. I had closed $\Omega^{\prime}$ whose real and imaginary parts represent linearly independent cohomology class with real coefficients.This $\Omega^{\prime}$ satisfied in $\omega^{n-1}\wedge \Omega \wedge \bar{\Omega}\neq0$ condition. Because this is open condition ,$\Omega^{\prime}$ can be change nearby the $\Omega$(this is case of question) whose real and imaginary parts represent linearly independent rational cohomology classes such that the condition hold.

Comment: However I can’t understand this statement “it is open condition $. What is it mean?

Comment: A simple example of an open condition is the following. Suppose we have a topological space $X$ and a continuous function $F$. Suppose we are interested in the subset of $X$ given by $F\ne 0$. Then this is an open subset of $X$. So the condition $F\ne 0$ is called open. Hope this makes sense. In the example that you want to understand the topological space is the space of couples $\omega$ and $\Omega$ and the condition $\omega^{n-1}\wedge \Omega\wedge \overline \Omega\ne 0$ is open, because if you slightly change both $\omega$ and $\Omega$, it still holds.

Comment: thanks a lot, it is illustrative.